# responsive youtube video inside fixed width DIV

Tags: html, css, responsive

I want to make a responsive embeded iframe youtube video inside a fixed width div

OR

Place the video in the center of the screen for desktop with width 750px and height 350 px.

The video in any case should be centered and should be responsive on mobile devices aswell.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Any code you've written for this?

Comment: You want, sure, then do it. And if you come across a problem we can help, but we won't DO IT for you, this is not what StackOverflow is about.

Comment: @elena  , use i had wrote a code but i am new here so i did not know the standards that i have to add my written codes , my problem was i wanted to make a responsive video inside fixed width div , and thanks i found a solution by using "@media "

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

**Css**

```
.video-container {
  position: relative; 
  padding-bottom: 56.25%; 
  height: 0; 
  overflow: hidden; 
  max-width: 100%;
}

.video-container iframe {
  position: absolute; 
  top: 0; 
  left: 0; 
  width: 100%; 
  height: 100%;
}
```

**Html**

```
<div class="video-container">
    <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/zdOmNiXvM3w?rel=0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen" width="640" height="480" frameborder="0">
    </iframe>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/80egz2aL/2/

Comment: @ahmedaboubakr you´re welcome, mark answer as accepted if this helped you :) here you are [More info](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1):

I used this code in CSS:

```
    @media (max-width: 950px)
        { 
    .video-responsive{
    overflow:hidden;
    padding-bottom:56.25%;
    position:relative;
    height:0;
}
.video-responsive iframe{
    left:0;
    top:0;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    position:absolute;
}
            }
```

And this in HTML:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 video-responsive" align="center" style="align-content: center; margin: 0px;"><iframe src="VIDEO URL" width="750" height="350" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; fullscreen" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>

      <br clear="all">
```

The video shows at the specified size (750x350px) on computers and it is fully responsive on smaller devices (smartphones, tablets,etc.).

Thanks! :)

PS: this works also when you embed Vimeo videos or any other content.

Answer (score 0):

**CSS**

```
  @media (max-width: 950px)
{
    .video-container {
        position: relative;
        padding-bottom: 56.25%;
        padding-top: 30px;
        height: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
    }

    .video-container iframe,
    .video-container object,
    .video-container embed {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }
   /* .video-wrapper {
        width: 640px;
        float:none;
        margin-left:auto;
        margin-right:auto;
        max-width: 100%;
    }*/
}
@media (min-width: 950px) {
    .video-container {
        position: relative;
        padding-bottom: 56.25%;
        padding-top: 30px;
        height: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
    }

    .video-container iframe,
    .video-container object,
    .video-container embed {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 950px;
        height: 350px;
    }
   .video-wrapper {
      width: 950px;
       height: 350px;
        float:none;
        margin-left:auto;
        margin-right:auto;
        max-width: 100%;
    }

}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="video-wrapper">
<div class="video-container">
    <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/5xxK8f7qe5A" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen>

    </iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: i put this and it worked for me , and thanks for all who helped me